# Why this kind of function invocation is wrong in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, function, invocation

I'd like to create an anonymous function and then invoke it immediately.

1) This will bring a syntax error. Why?

```
function ()
{
    alert("hello");
}();
```

2) wrap the function definition with () and it works.

```
(function ()
{
    alert("hello");
})();
```

3) or, assign the anonymous function to a variable. It works.

```
var dummy = function()
{
    alert("hello");
}();
```

Why the first way doesn't work?

Comment: So apparently it's not a syntax error?

Comment: As sth said, it is a syntax error

Answer (score 13):

The [ECMAScript Language Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm), section 12.4, says:

> An *ExpressionStatement* cannot start
>   with the `function` keyword because that
>   might make it ambiguous with a
>   *FunctionDeclaration*.

So your case 1 is not allowed, because it might lead to ambiguities in the language. The other cases are different kinds of statements (not *ExpressionStatement*s) in which this is not a problem, so the construct is allowed there.