# Why need I wrap anonymous function in parenthesis before calling it in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, clojure

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Why this kind of function invocation is wrong in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670623/why-this-kind-of-function-invocation-is-wrong-in-javascript)
>   [Is there any reason to wrap anonymous JavaScript functions in braces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2137826/is-there-any-reason-to-wrap-anonymous-javascript-functions-in-braces)

Is there a good explanation why I have to wrap an anonymous functions in parentheses before I can call it, like this:

```
(function() { alert('foo'); })();
```

instead of just

```
function() { alert('foo'); }();
```

?

There are other languages in which functions are just things you can pass around, like for example Clojure. In Clojure a function call looks like this: (function args), for example: (+ 1 2). You can just substitute an anonymous function anywhere you would normally use a named function: ((fn [a b] (+ a b)) 1 2). In Javascript this seems not to be the case.

Comment: or even this `(function() { alert('foo'); }());`

Comment: So you know, there are many ways to make it an anonymous function expression besides the parentheses. For example `+function() { alert('foo'); }();`. You may encounter a specific issue if you use parentheses.

Comment: The simplest way I think this could be explained (probably the worst) - as functions are objects and vice versa, so adding brackets around the function, you are making an object out of a definition.

Answer (score 1):

Because without parentheses around the function, the code is a bad function declaration and adding the `()` to its end is a syntax error.

With parentheses around the function, however, you get a function pointer to an anonymous function which can be executed by adding `()` to its end.