# Why are not top level anonymous functions allowed in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, function, lambda

For example, in `test.js` this is allowed (and extremely pointless):

```
1 + 2;
(function () {});
```

When executing with node:

```
$ node test.js
$
```

The form `function () {}` (without parentheses) is allowed in other contexts, for example as an argument to another function.

Why is not the following allowed in the top level of a JavaScript file?

```
function () {};
```

Comment: Why do you need this? A name-less function without any handles to it is just a noop!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why need I wrap anonymous function in parenthesis before calling it in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8583145/why-need-i-wrap-anonymous-function-in-parenthesis-before-calling-it-in-javascrip)

Comment: @EmilVikström I certainly don't need it. I'm merely curious as to why it works that way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A statement that starts with `function` is a function *statement*.
Function statements must be named. (since they create a declaration in that scope)

Comment: The precise term would be *function declaration* afaik.

Comment: @FelixKling: Not according to Firefox: `SyntaxError: function statement requires a name`

Comment: Maybe in JavaScript, but according to ECMAScript: http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-13

Comment: Mozilla Firefox uses `FunctionStatement` as an extension of a `FunctionDecleration` (but this is afaik. non-standard). A great explanation can be found here: http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/07/06/function-declarations-vs-function-expressions/

Comment: @SLaks—ECMAScript has only [FunctionDeclaration](http://es5.github.com/#x13) and [FunctionExpression](http://es5.github.com/#x13), *FunctionStatement* is a Mozilla JavaScript thing (as Saebekassebil said).

Comment: But in the expressions I used I didn't name the functions, thus they do not have to be named?

Comment: @AdamLindberg: Functions **declarations** must be named.  Function **expressions** do not need to be named.

Comment: @SLaks Ah, I see. Thanks! Perhaps clarify that in the answer?