# What's wrong with my Immediately Invoked Function Expression?

Tags: javascript, iife

i've tried to do a very simple IIFE below,

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var obj = new Object;

    (function(_obj) {_obj.prop = 'defined';})(obj);

    if(typeof obj.prop === undefined)
     alert('undefined');
    else
     alert(obj.prop);

</script>
```

Why does the script alert "undefined" than "defined" as a result?

**@EDIT**

The script shoud have worked as expected except:

- The unintended `typeof obj.prop === undefined` is wrong, but `obj.prop === undefined` should be used instead.
- When omitting parenthesis below, the script doesn't work as expected but none of syntax error is raised from rhino.

  `function(_obj) {_obj.prop = 'defined';}(obj);`

Comment: Although your comparison is wrong (`typeof obj.prop` returns a string, so `typeof obj.prop === undefined` will **always** be `false` and I don't think you intended to do this), it alerts `defined`. Please create http://jsfiddle.net/ to replicate your problem, the posted code does not show the behaviour you say it does, so we cannot help you.

Comment: More people probably run into the `typeof obj.prop === undefined` bug than the redefining `undefined` bug that it's supposed to fix.

Comment: So is your question now why omitting the parenthesis doesn't work? If so, it's a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/670623/218196

Comment: Yes, `typeof obj.prop` returns a string. corrected.

Comment: sof: Don't change your question. @FelixKling: I'm going to roll it back.

Comment: No, omitting the parenthesis doesn't work.

Comment: @Felix Kling: Yes, it's duplicate. but none of syntax error is raised when omitting the parenthesis.

Comment: I get one: *SyntaxError: Unexpected token (*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code alerts `'defined'` but for the wrong reason.

This...

```
typeof obj.prop === undefined
```

should be this...

```
obj.prop === undefined
```

...because `typeof` returns a string representing the type of object.

---

Don't use the `typeof` hack when testing for `undefined`. It's confusing, and can be the source of bugs such as the one you encountered.

If you're that worried about `undefined` being redefined, then do this...

```
obj.prop === void 0
```

Comment: Why is using `typeof` a hack? What's wrong with `typeof obj.prop === "undefined"`?

Comment: @FelixKling It's a hack because it's a way of getting around a presumed problem rather than dealing with the problem directly *(when it actually exists)*. IMO, it's embarrassingly ugly code that isn't well representative of what is desired. Also, it's probably the source of more bugs like the one in the question than the bugs it's supposed to avoid.

Comment: @amnotiam Stuff like `typeof foo.bar !== 'function'` is fine though... The `typeof` operator has its applications.

Answer (score 1):

Should be:

```
if ( typeof obj.prop === 'undefined' )
```

The `typeof` operator returns strings.

Answer (score 1):

`typeof` returns a string.  So, you need;

```
if(typeof obj.prop === "undefined")
```

The code seems to work as expected after you fix this issue: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/KJBjG/

Comment: That's correct but does not explain the behaviour the OP is experiencing (I'm not implying that there is an explanation).

Comment: @FelixKling - Once this issue is fixed, I can't reproduce the OP's results [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/KJBjG/) and the code seems to work as expected.  I would doubt they can either.

Comment: Me too... I'm just talkative today ;)